# Migrated Wordpress MS to new server, it wont send mail

Tags: wordpress, centos, sendmail, cpanel

A while ago I moved from Knownhost to Liquidweb, migrated Cpanel / CentOS and my wordpress app (and others) has a hard time letting the PHP Mail engine send mail out from third party domains. However, it is only problematic on my existing multisite install. I have setup a new multisite to see if its a problem with the server itself

The Domain, the DB Names, etc - were all the exact same. So I cannot tell why it will not send mail (php mail function) on behalf of the administrators and third party domains. It attempts to send, it does not fire a log, but somewhere in that config it is blocked.

The same server, on a different account/domain allows mail from 3rd party domains in the phpmail funciton, both share security policies. I am at a complete loss.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you try to ask that problem to your hosting support

Comment: Yes, they insist it is not hosting related. It could be in the CPanel migration; but the same server can have a new domain with same setup send mail through masked/"send as" domains